# Update on Phonegap Storage and Databases

Tags: database, cordova, mobile, maps, offline

I'm working on a MapBox/Leaflet map where I would like to store a map locally, with locked bounds, over a small city that plays music in each pin in a Phonegap project and new to all of this. For this I know I will need to use a database, and saw [tbicr's demo project's](https://github.com/tbicr/OfflineMap) where he demo's offline Mapbox and Leaflet maps using IndexedDB and WebSQL and thought this was perfect as [Phonegap's storage support page](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) says they support WebSQL and IndexedDB OR plugins. Therefor I can simply wrap these have it work in Phonegap. I tried and this isn't the case. They seem to not display anything or only display one tile level, and I looked into more things on the Phonegap side like statements missing in the index or config file. So

1. **Can anyone give me an Update on Cordova storage?**
2. **Am I miss understanding or miss something in the scope of understanding the problem?**
3. **Is there a better approach?**

Also read that I DO need a plugin called Polyfill for WebSQL in Phonegap and because of the fast nature of Phonegap and many things I read seem to be outdated I was wanting an update of phonegap's storage.

Answer (score 0):

@Garrett, I can only tell you about one (1) webSQL, aka SQLite. Worked stopped on that because everyone was using [the same implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_SQL_Database). However, webSQL is still available in various plugins. NOTE, webSQL is a library, not a server, so it is much lighter than other solutions.

[CanIUse.com says](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage) IE & Firefox have not implement yet, most others have, including Safari.